# Java Cannot Find Symbol (c9.io)

Tags: java

I'm following [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm) tutorial, and I'm using C9 to run/compile my code. I followed the instructions on the page, but I added some values. When I build my code, it gives me a `cannot find symbol` error. Here's the `Contact.java` and `ContactTest.java`.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Contact {

    String name;
    int age;
    String occupation;
    String address;
    String number;

    public Contact(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void conAge(int conAge) {
        age = conAge;
    }
    public void conOcc(String conOcc) {
        occupation = conOcc;
    }
    public void conAdd(String conAdd) {
        address = conAdd;
    }
    public void conNum(String conNum) {
        number = conNum;
    }
    public void printContact() {
        System.out.println("Name:"+name);
        System.out.println("Age:"+age);
        System.out.println("Occupation:"+occupation);
        System.out.println("Address:"+address);
        System.out.println("Number:"+number);
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.*;

public class ContactTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Contact contactOne = new Contact("Felix Martin");
        Contact contactTwo = new Contact("Jihad Fair");

        contactOne.conAge = 15;
        contactOne.conOcc = "Student";
        contactOne.conAdd = "3550 Vista Park Drive";
        contactOne.conNum = "(319)-631-8592";
        contactOne.printContact();

        contactTwo.conAge = 15;
        contactTwo.conOcc = "Student";
        contactTwo.conAdd = "49 Amber Ln";
        contactTwo.conNum = "(319)-820-1976";
        contactTwo.printContact();
    }
}
```

Here's the error that the builder/compiler gives me. Note that I'm VERY new to java, and I barely understand the errors it's giving me.

```
Building workspace
src/ContactTest.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        contactOne.conAge = 15;
                  ^
  symbol:   variable conAge
  location: variable contactOne of type Contact
src/ContactTest.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        contactOne.conOcc = "Student";
                  ^
  symbol:   variable conOcc
  location: variable contactOne of type Contact
src/ContactTest.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        contactOne.conAdd = "3550 Vista Park Drive";
                  ^
  symbol:   variable conAdd
  location: variable contactOne of type Contact
src/ContactTest.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        contactOne.conNum = "(319)-631-8592";
                  ^
  symbol:   variable conNum
  location: variable contactOne of type Contact
src/ContactTest.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        contactTwo.conAge = 15;
                  ^
  symbol:   variable conAge
  location: variable contactTwo of type Contact
src/ContactTest.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        contactTwo.conOcc = "Student";
                  ^
  symbol:   variable conOcc
  location: variable contactTwo of type Contact
src/ContactTest.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        contactTwo.conAdd = "49 Amber Ln";
                  ^
  symbol:   variable conAdd
  location: variable contactTwo of type Contact
src/ContactTest.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        contactTwo.conNum = "(319)-820-1976";
                  ^
  symbol:   variable conNum
  location: variable contactTwo of type Contact
8 errors
Done!
```

Comment: Are both classes in different packages? It might be that you are not allowed to acces the variables directly due to the visibility of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the members are methods not fields

```
contactOne.conAge(15);
```

Use the same approach for the `conOcc`, `conAdd` & `conNum` methods

Comment: Thank you. I'm not really into Java yet, so I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
contactOne.conAge(15);
```

You declared conAge as set method, not a field.

Comment: Thanks man. Im accepting Reimeuses answer because I received it first, but thanks either way!